# Webpack 3 and React - How to refer to file outside of bundle?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, webpack

I have a react app, that is bundled into a `main.<hash>.js` file, and uploaded to an S3 bucket.  I need to be able to reference a `json` file (that the contents gets updated daily) from within a react component.  The json files lives in the root of the S3 bucket, but its outside of the bundle.

Is this possible?  I've tried multiple variations of import statements in the react component that uses the json file, but it means it only refers to the `json` file that was there at build time.

The main issue I'm having is how to read a file outside the bundle at runtime, when the file is not available during build time.

Comment: use copy-webpack-plugin for that

Comment: does that still not require the json file be there at build time?  In my case it won't

Comment: You'll have to require that anyways, but you'll be able to modify the file since it won't have hashs and stuff.

Comment: you can have a stub file just to build, you can modify later

Comment: @PlayMa256 ok, I tried that and I can see how that would work - my last question is how do I get a reference to that file in the build directory now from the react component? Thanks